# Win2k3 password Authentication using LDAP in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, ldap

I need to implement the Win2k3 password validation policy. As my application resides on Win2k3 cane we validate the password directly with windows domain password by using LDAP. This is because application design does not want to store 8/more password entry into DB and validate new password against that. As Windows already does same thing and using LDAP we can lookup into windows server.

Can any one please let me know LDAP API to fulfill above requirement in VC++.

Answer (score 1):

There is an API that Secure Ops, Novell's Identity Manager, and other products use to plugin to the password change functionality. (I do not know the API name, sorry).

It requires a password filter installed on each domain controller, since the only time it can catch the clear text password to try and do anything with it is when it is being changed, and it might be changed on any given DC at any moment in time.